# Symbolic comparison of recursive functions

Tags: symbolic, recursion

I would like to  test two recursive functions for equality for all arguments. So far I have this:

```
f[0]:=1

f[n_] := n f[n - 1]

ForAll[x,  x>=0, f[x]==f[x]]
```

It is clear that the result must be  true. But I get this:

```
∀{x},x≥0 Hold[f[x]==f[x]]
```

Why and what would be the best way to do so?

Every tip is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For one, your `f` is recursive, so I recommend memoization. i.e. change the second definition to `f[n_] := f[n] = n f[n - 1]`. That way, values of each `f[n]` is saved and does not have to be re-evaluated (significantly reduces time required to compute for high `n` values). That being said, you get an error message with your code because the `x` in `f[x]` is not an integer. Subtracting `1` repeatedly never gets to `0`. You can solve this by limiting the input to integers only. i.e. change the second line to `f[n_Integer] := f[n] = n f[n - 1]`.

Comment: Don't you get an error from your code? If so, what is it? It might be a clue.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve with your last command `ForAll` ?

Comment: @yarchik I use Mathematica only for one day. I try to write a model checking procedure for software components and do not know how to compare two functions symbolically. So the easiest way, as for inexperienced user, was to make functions have all possible arguments to say that for the same input the components (functions) have the same output. Ideally it would be great to learn how to unfold the functions automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the recursion will only stop for positive integer values of the argument, the argument should be explicitly restricted.

```
Clear[f1];
f1[0] = 1;
f1[n_Integer?Positive] := f1[n] = n f1[n - 1];
```

A closed-form solution can be found with [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
Clear[f2];
f2[n_] = f2[n] /. RSolve[{f2[n] == n*f2[n - 1], f2[0] == 1}, f2[n], n][[1]]

(*  Pochhammer[1, n]  *)
```

The functions are identical for nonnegative integer arguments

```
And @@ Table[f1[n] == f2[n] == n!, {n, 0, 100}]

(*  True  *)
```

However, the closed-form expression is not limited to integer values of the argument.

```
Show[
 DiscretePlot[f1[n], {n, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[f2[n], {n, -3, 4.1}, PlotRange -> {0, (4.1)!}],
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 4.1}, {0, (4.1)!}}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**  Alternatively, using [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
f3[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[f1 /@ Range[10], n]

(*  n!  *)
```

`f2` and `f3` are just alternate representations and are equal for all `n`

```
f2[n] == f3[n] // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, Bob! One question: what does this "And @@ Table[f1[n] == f2[n] == n!, {n, 0, 100}]" mean and why is it not this possible to compare the functions symbolically, by writing f1[t]==f2[t], letting Mathematica symbolically unfold these functions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IgorShumeiko - `f1` is not defined for a symbolic argument so `f1[t]` cannot be evaluated unless `t` is given a specific nonnegative integer value. The `Table` does the comparison for specific numeric values and returns a list of `True/False` values. `And@@list` applies the logical `And` to the `list` and evaluates to `True` only if all list values are `True`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ask this because I would like to prove something like this (very simplified example):

`S1[0,a_]=0`  
`S1[t_,a_]:=S1[t-1,a]+1/; a[t-1]`  
`S1[t_,a_]:=0/; !a[t-1]` 
 
`S2[0,a_]=0`  
`S2[t_,a_]:=S2[t-1,a]+2/; a[t-1]`  
`S2[t_,a_]:=0/; !a[t-1]`  

`S1[t,port]==2*S2[t,port]` Since the function port[t] is unknown, I assume that it must be done symbolically.

Comment: @IgorShumeiko - I cannot make sense of your comment the way it is formatted. Recommend that you open a new question and use proper code blocks to ask your question.

Comment: Makes sense. [new question link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127733/model-checking-with-mathematica-comparison-of-recursive-functions-where-argumen)

Answer (score 5):

Okay so first the solution:

```
Clear[f]
f[0]=1;
f[n_?NumericQ]:=n f[n-1]
ForAll[x,x>=0,f[x]==f[x]]
```

> True

So what happened here?

1. I added
   [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) so
   your old definitions does not interfere with us.
2. I changed your f[0] to a [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) instead of a [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)
3. I added a `?NumericQ` behind your function parameter. So why does that help? Well if we would leave the `x` in there, we'll get a infinite recursion because it will not reach zero. The `?NumericQ` argument waits for a numeric input. If the function does not get one, it keeps unevaluated. And ForAll knows that a function (whatever it is) which equals itself, is always true.

Does that answer your question?

Btw.: You should also listen to [the Comment from JHM](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127704/symbolic-comparison-of-recursive-functions#comment345383_127704) and implementing memoization.

Comment: Thanks for very much for the answer. What if we have two functions, let us assume they are the same, and we write at the end: `ForAll[x,x>=0,f[x]==g[x]]`. It gives out `∀ x,x≥0 f[x]==g[x]`, which is not that I expected. How to get "true"? If I write `g[x]==f[x]`, it says `g[x]==f[x]`. I just need to check whether they can be unfolded to the same expressions. Thanks for your help!