# Model-checking with Mathematica. Comparison of recursive functions where argument is unknown function

Tags: function-construction, recursion

I would like to try some model-checking with recursive functions. The way it can be programmed with Mathematica (from my perspective) is following:

```
 S1[0,a_]=0 
 S1[t_,a_]:=S1[t-1,a]+1/; a[t-1] 
 S1[t_,a_]:=0/; !a[t-1]

 S2[0,a_]=0 
 S2[t_,a_]:=S2[t-1,a]+2/; a[t-1] 
 S2[t_,a_]:=0/; !a[t-1]  

 S1[t,port]==2*S2[t,port]
```

Functions `S1` and `S2` get two arguments; time -- integer value and port function -- a function that takes time and  returns a Boolean value.

Note, that function `port[t]`, that returns Boolean value, is not known beforehand.  But the value of `S1` and `S2` depend on the port  value from the previous moment of time (`a[t-1]`). I guess  that comparison must be done symbolically after unfolding the `S1[t]` and `S2[t]` functions.

Since what I have so far  is a pretty much pseudo code, I would like to ask what would be the best way to do so, if it is possible at all with Mathematica.

Every tip is highly appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Do you wish to check that S1 and S2 have equivalent definitions? Or that they take the same value at a finite set of times? You obviously can't check that they take the same values at an infinite set of times.

Comment: @mikado Thanks for the comment. So you think in this case it is not possible to write something like this: `ForAll[x,  x>=0, S1[x]==2*S2[x]]`